# How to remove grub loader command line after deleting ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, windows-10

I wanted to remove ubuntu mate and install normal ubuntu 17.10 so i followed the online tutorial telling me to go into windows disk management and then deleting the ubuntu partition and extending a normal partition into the now unallocated partition. But then when i restarted I landed on what was called the grub recovery command line. I restarted again and pressed f12 to get into the bios settings and then booted into windows. I changed the boot sequence through advanced startup and put windows boot manager on top so now i am directly booting into windows but in my bios, the ubuntu option still shows whenever I do advanced startup on windows.

i want to completely remove ubuntu so i can install ubuntu 17.10 through a bootable usb. Can someone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Fix the MBR? https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/

Comment: @arochester The problem's description clearly points to UEFI, not BIOS/MBR.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu again and it should update UEFI boot entries. Unused boot entries at UEFI is NOT a problem but if you want, you can edit those from Windows or Ubuntu (different tools) or UEFI itself.